# Exportacion de Excel a SQL server

Tags: sql, sql-server, excel, sql-server-2014, sql-server-2017

Estoy intento subir los datos de un archivo de Excel a SQL Server pero me manda este error como se soluciona esto?[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tienes que instalarte el driver ACE.OLEDB adecuado a tu instalación. Lo puedes bajar [desde aquí](https://www.microsoft.com/es-es/download/details.aspx?id=13255).

Ten en cuenta que si tu Office (Excel) es de 32 bits deberás instalar la versión del driver también de 32 bits, de otra forma tampoco te funcionaría.

Comment: muchas gracias, intentare instalarlo mas tarde